# Rails, no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer when using .find on a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a search trough a database for the current user, but get this error when passing in my .find params `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`. I have the current user params stored in @current_user, and want to find all the articles written by this user (Ie searching for current_user.id in the column called user_id). I am new to ruby and can't figure out what's going on here by googling, any help is appreciated.

application controller:

```
helper_method :current_user

def current_user
   @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

articles controller:

```
def manage
  @article = Article.find(current_user.id[:user_id])
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
   attr_accessor :password
   ...
   has_many :article
end
```

article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: `current_user.id` is the id you want to search for. I.e. `@article = Article.find(current_user.id)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change this to

```
Article.where(user_id: current_user.id)
```

But the better way would be to just use the association you've created (do change it to `has_many :articles` first)

```
current_user.articles
```

`find_by_user_id` or `find_by(user_id: current_user.id)` would work but only return one article.

Comment: This is the best answer. Use the associations.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between using `.where`, `.find_by_user_id` and `current_user.articles` ? Honestly, I like using the association the most, because it's the shortest way to type it, but I would like to hear (or read, if you can link documentation/guides about this) arguments in terms of memory usage, code versions and so on

Comment: Associations are the idiomatic way of doing this. Any performance difference would be minimal

Comment: Here's the rails guide for your has_many association from users to articles. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association